# Magento 1.9.x Discounts deducted from Excl. Tax Price even when Including Tax is set in Apply Discount On Prices Settings

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax, discount, price-rules

We struggle to make our Discount/Tax calculation working alright - we tried all possible settings and nothing seems to work as we need (and what we assume as usual need).

**We need:** Discount to be deducted from Incl. Tax prices, and tax calculation to happen after discount.

**Example:**

Product subtotal excl. Tax = 100.00
Product subtotal incl. Tax (VAT 20 %) = 120.00
Discount (Fixed amount discount for whole cart) = 70.00

Having following settings set in **Tax > Calculation Settings**:

- [Apply Customer Tax] - After Discount
- [Apply Discount On Prices] - Including Tax
- [Apply Tax On] - Custom Price if available

**We would assume this calculation logic:**

Total paid by the customer = 50.00 (120 - 70)
Tax (VAT 20 %) = 10.00 (50 * 0.2)

**However, what we get is this:**

Total paid by the customer = 30.00
Tax (VAT 20 %) = 6.00 (30 * 0.2)

**What is happening is this:**
Discount gets deducted from Excl. Tax Price, instead of Incl. Tax Price (although it is the one which is set in Settings!).

Interestingly, if we change settings of [Apply Customer Tax] to "Before Discount", discounts (both fixed amounts or %) get deducted from Incl. Tax Price. Unfortunately we cannot use this option, as in this case tax get (obviously) calculated from before the discount price.

So the question is - what can we do to make the combination of

[Apply Customer Tax] - After Discount
[Apply Discount On Prices] - Including Tax

work as discount being deducted from Incl. Tax prices & tax being calculated from post-discount total? We assume it should work absolutely fine but it does not in our case and our IT agency cannot find a way to fix it.

If any of you have experience with this, we would be very grateful if you share your knowledge.

[Magento ver. 1.9.3.0]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi BlueC, unfortunately we did not. Do you have any solution or ideas what could help? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Filip no solution here, I think I am probably going to look at rewriting some of the methods in Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax but it's pretty complicated stuff. Another option is just to edit the template so it displays the correct calculation even if the stored calculation is wrong.

Comment: I understand. Good luck with that. If you manage to devise any solution and are willing to share that with us, please let me know! Thank you.